# PCKIDRetrievalTool gives error - Error: the data couldn't be sent to cache server

Tags: intel, sgx

I am trying to run below command on a production server:

```
PCKIDRetrievalTool -url https://ip:post/sgx/certification/v1/platforms -user_token value -use_secure_cert false -proxy_type direct
```

And I am getting error-

```
Intel(R) Software Guard Extensions PCK Cert ID Retrieval Tool Version 1.19.100.3

Error: unexpected error occurred while sending data to cache server.
Error: the data couldn't be sent to cache server!
```

The error is very general. Where should I look for more information.